# How to convert HTML to Pdf with OpenPdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, openpdf

How can I convert an HTML to PDF with [OpenPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF)?

For what I know, OpenPdf is a fork of Itext 4. Unluckily I can't find Itext 4 documentation.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: what about this? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.0

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: it was published by Itext Software. See also this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.2

Comment: iText 4.2.2 was put there by me personally. It is a redirection POM that redirects to the iText 5 release that was current at the time. It's how iText Software regained control over the hijacked groupId, as described in the article linked above.

Comment: iText 4.2.0 was published by weiyeh, who was an employee of InProTopia.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse And this means that "Itext 4 does not exists" is not true. And anyway, definitively you're not helping me, furthermore for personal reasons.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok,it seems you can't do it directly with only OpenPDF, you have to use [Flying Saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer): get [flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf) and then use it. An example:

```
String inputFile = "my.xhtml";
String outputFile = "generated.pdf";

String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();

try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputFile))) {
    renderer.createPDF(os);
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/sreeprasad/3233907).

PS: FlyingSaucer expects XHTML syntax. If you have some problems with yout HTML file, you could use [Jsoup](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup):

```
String inputFile = "my.html";
String outputFile = "generated.pdf";

String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)));
final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(document.html());
renderer.layout();

try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputFile))) {
    renderer.createPDF(os);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Kotlin HTML to PDF.  Jsoup is not required.

```kotlin
fun pdfFromHtml(ostream: OutputStream, html: String) {
    val renderer = ITextRenderer()
    val sharedContext = renderer.sharedContext
    sharedContext.isPrint = true
    sharedContext.isInteractive = false
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html)
    renderer.layout()
    renderer.createPDF(ostream)
}
```

Here's one with Jsoup.

```kotlin
fun pdfFromHtml(ostream:OutputStream, html: String) {
    val renderer = ITextRenderer()
    val sharedContext = renderer.sharedContext
    sharedContext.isPrint = true
    sharedContext.isInteractive = false
    val document = Jsoup.parse(html)
    document.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml)
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(document.html())
    renderer.layout()
    renderer.createPDF(ostream)
}
```